# match case positive integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to match positive integer in Python?

```py
match n:
    case >=0:
        print('positive int')
```

Causes a syntax error

---

More succinctly than

```py
match n:
    case n if n >= 0:
```

---

I want to match all of these cases:

```
case n is not a non-negative integer
case n == 0
case n == 1
case n > 1
```

Comment: Using a guard is the way (although I would put `case int() if n >= 0`). What's the problem?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Match is cool when it fits your problem, but if it doesn't fit, remember that everything `match` can do can also be done with good old-fashioned `if`/`else` statements.

Comment: I'm guess this is a toy example, but you can flip things and `match n >= 0`

Comment: If you don't like `match n: case n if n >= 0:` then just write `if n>=0:`

Comment: Just being pedantic but zero is not a positive number

Comment: @wim problem is, feels so defeating to use match statement when it leads to more verbose code than ugly if/elif chains

Comment: @JonSG yeah it's just one case. I would like to have cases for all of "n not non-negative int", "n == 0",  "n == 1", "n > 1"

Comment: You don't have a chain. Maybe if you show us a chain, we can help improve that.

Comment: @minseong Yes, well this may be a case where an if/elif is just better than structural pattern match (you're checking a value condition, after all, not really matching on any "structure")